# Appending multiple rows into a single row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is a followup from the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459414/appending-multiple-rows-in-one-row).

This is my dataframe:

```
nan = ""
d = {'NAME': ['a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','c','d','d','d','d','d','d'],
 'col1': ['P100','P100','P100','P100','MS','MS','MS','MS','MS','MS','MS','MS','MS','MS','MS'],
 'col2': ['CNMZ',
  'CNMZ',
  'COMX',
  'COMX',
  '_NCTE',
  '_NCTE',
  '_NCTE',
  '_NCTE',
  '_NCTE',
  'T1MF',
  'T1MF',
  'T1MF',
  'T1MF',
  'T1MF',
  'T1MF'],
 'stepNo': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 'col4': ['xyz',
  'abc',
  'pqr',
  'gvt',
  'mno',
  'tru',
  'ercm',
  'lotr',
  'ddlj',
  'refv',
  'ecv',
  'ecv',
  'ecv',
  'ecv',
  'ecv'],
 'col5': ['PHL',
  'PHL',
  'BHL',
  'ALT',
  'MRS',
  'MRS',
  'TUL',
  'MRS',
  'FAT',
  'PHL',
  'PHL',
  'JEN',
  'FTW',
  'AMB',
  'KGP'],
 'col6': ['CP',
  'CO',
  'CP',
  'CO',
  'CP',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'RT',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'CP',
  'CO',
  'CO'],
 'col7': ['PHL',
  'PHL',
  'ALT',
  'ALT',
  'MRS',
  'TUL',
  'MRS',
  'FAT',
  'FAH',
  'PHL',
  'JEN',
  'FTW',
  'AMB',
  'KGP',
  'KGP'],
 'col8': ['CO',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'RT',
  'CP',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'CP',
  'CO',
  'CO',
  'CO'],
 'col9': ['SID',
  'M/M',
  'SID',
  'U/D',
  'AL LO',
  'AL LO',
  'AL LO',
  'AL LO',
  'AL LO',
  'M/M',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS'],
 'col10': ['SID',
  'M/M',
  'SID',
  'U/D',
  'AL LO',
  '3 M',
  '3 M',
  'M/M',
  'AL LO',
  'M/M',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS'],
 'col11': [nan,
  'ATM',
  nan,
  'PACK',
  'AL LP',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DAM',
  'DAM',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'M/M'],
 'col12': [nan,
  'SID',
  nan,
  'PACK',
  'CAL LO',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'M/M',
  'CAL LO',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'DCS',
  'AL LO'],
 'col13': ['abc',
  '-02-1_',
  '-1',
  '-13_',
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  'T1_VT1.',
  nan,
  '-06',
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  '-03_02-03'],
 'col14': [nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  nan,
  '102/',
  '102/',
  '102/',
  nan,
  '101/',
  nan,
  '3405',
  '3102/',
  '3111/',
  '3102/',
  nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to print row with same value in `NAME` in a single row with all columns using the `stepNo`. For eg.

Output:

```
NAME   col1    col2   stepNo  col4...........col14    NAME col1   col2   stepNo   col4...........col14   NAME   col1    col2   stepNo  col4...........col14    NAME col1   col2   stepNo   col4...........col14
 a     P100    CNMZ     1      xyz            nan       a  P100   CNMZ     2       abc            nan
 b     P100    COMX     1      pqr            nan       b  P100   COMX     2       gvt            nan
 c      MS    _NCTE     1      mno            102/      c   MS   _NCTE     2       tru            102/   c      MS    _NCTE     3      ercm           102/     c    MS   _NCTE     4       lotr           nan
```

Since `NAME=3` has 5 row there will be 1 more sets of columns in the output.

For `NAME=4` there will be 6 sets of columns in the output.

I hope the example output is descriptive enough. If not you can refer the linked question at the beginning for better understanding.

This was the suggested solution but it fails for the above example:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(min(df['stepNo']), max(df['stepNo'])+1):
    dfs.append(df[df['stepNo']==i].reset_index())
dfx = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
dfx.drop(inplace=True, columns=['index'])
```

Is it possible to get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map_name = dict( enumerate(df['NAME'].factorize()[1] ) )
map_name = dict(map(reversed, map_name.items()))
df2 = np.zeros((df.NAME.nunique(), df.stepNo.max() * len(df.columns))).astype(object)

for i,g in df.groupby(['NAME','stepNo']):

    df2[map_name[i[0]], (i[1]-1)*len(df.columns):(i[1])*len(df.columns)] = g.values

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2.columns = np.tile(df.columns, df.stepNo.max())
df2['stepNo'] = df2['stepNo'].astype(int)
```

Comment: `NAME` column is a string value, I have updated dataframe to reflect that . I am getting type error for str cant be converted to int

Comment: Still getting the same error. its on line 3 of your code.  `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: stepNo is int or str? There are difference among the df you report here and your real df maybe

Comment: stepNo is int in the dataframe.

Comment: ok perfect... have you tried to run the code only on the df you reported here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213417/discussion-between-murtaza-haji-and-marco-cerliani).