# access column in pandas using column number and filter rows on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns of same name, which causes `.loc` to fail when accessing by column name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 'xyz'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['xyz', 'abc']], columns=['max_speed', 'max_speed'])
```

I am trying the following method mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50186506/7515189) but its not successful.

```
df.loc[df.columns[0] == 'abc']

df.loc[df.columns[1].str.contains('xyz')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pandas is best not working with duplicated columns names.

If need select by position columns names use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df[df.iloc[:, 0] == 'abc']
df[df.iloc[:, 1].str.contains('xyz')]
```

Comment: Yes , I know :P. 
This is a special case stemming from this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674725/appending-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-pandas