# Merge fails when dataframe has multiple columns with same name

Tags: python, pandas

This is a followup from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61997418/access-column-in-pandas-using-column-number-and-filter-rows-on-condition).

I am trying to merge two dataframe on a common column , but one dataframe has multiple columns with same name. I want to use that column to merge.

These are my dataframes:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 'xyz'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['xyz', 'abc']], columns=['max_speed', 'min_speed'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 'xyz'], ['abc', 'xyz'], ['xyz', 'abc']], columns=['max_speed', 'max_speed'])
```

I have a special case where my dataframe has multiple columns with same name([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674725/appending-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-in-pandas)).

I tried using the location of the column rather than name of the column to access but didnt work

What I tried:

```py
df3 = df1.merge(df2, right_on=df1.columns[0],left_on=df2.columns[0])
```

Error:

> ValueError: The column label 'max_speed' is not unique.

Let me know how can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `set_index` with the column in the position you want in `df2`, then use `merge` with `right_index=True`.

```
print (df1.merge(df2.set_index(df2.iloc[:,0])
                    .iloc[:, 1:], #to select only the other column max_speed
                 left_on='max_speed', right_index=True, 
                 suffixes=('','_'))
      )
  max_speed min_speed max_speed_
0       abc       xyz        xyz
0       abc       xyz        xyz
1       abc       xyz        xyz
1       abc       xyz        xyz
2       xyz       abc        abc
```

Comment: Can I keep only the first `max_speed` column? Basically I have over 10-15 max_speed columns in the other df. So it would be good to have only one max_speed at the end.

Comment: @MurtazaHaji not sure to understand what you want. the fact there are already 2 column with same name is not intuitive. the way I understand is either in the iloc it could be `.iloc[:, 1:2]` to keep only one other column max_speed from df2, or just select the first N columns, where N is the number of column from df1, on the result of the merge